# recycle view is not going away

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

UPDATED:

I want to display "no items in the list" when there is actually nothing to display in a recyclerview in a fragment. This is what I am trying:

in my fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f0f0f0"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/assigned_recycler"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:animationCache="true"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empty_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="@string/no_data_available" />
```

in my fragment's java file:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_assigned_orders, container, false);


    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.assigned_recycler);


    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);




    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


    mAdapter = new AssignedOrdersListAdapter(orderService.getAssignedOrders());
    mAdapter.setManager(getFragmentManager());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Assigned");

    emptyViewText = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);


    new LegDistanceTask().execute("");
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public  void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("OrderUpdate"));

   int count = mAdapter.getItemCount();
    if(count==0){

        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        emptyViewText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Also does it have to do something with my layout code and color?

Comment: ideally you shouldn't do it in onViewCreated because your recyclerview state can change often based on how you get data. so you should do it after you get the data. if its service call then in the post execute of async task. plus did you do findviewbyid for recycler view as well? its not here in code

Comment: Hi Kapsym, Where should I put it then? I have verified that the count does return 0 and service call completes successfully before onViewCreatred is called. I have tried putting it in onResume of the fragment too.

Comment: Check if you are changing visibility somewhere else in the code. I just tried it and seems to work fine

Comment: And can you add the findviewbyid code of recyclerview here as well?

Comment: done. I posted the entire code again and changed the method call to onResume

Comment: Not sure what is the issue.  In your service call when it gets completed do you do some changes on visibility of recycler view. From this code it doesn't look to be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below code in `onCreateView`,

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_assigned_orders, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.assigned_recycler);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Assigned");
        emptyViewText = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);

        if(orderService.getAssignedOrders().size() != 0) {
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            emptyViewText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mAdapter = new AssignedOrdersListAdapter(orderService.getAssignedOrders());
            mAdapter.setManager(getFragmentManager());
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            emptyViewText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        new LegDistanceTask().execute("");
        return rootView;
    }
```

The above code will check whether the list received from service is empty or not and display the components accordingly.

You should be checking the list size to determine, not the adapter count.

Comment: Yes. That worked. Must have been the way I was using the getItemCount() logic. Or the conditional statement.

Comment: Happy coding.. :)

Comment: Many Thanks for the help :)